# SiriKit - During the resolution of intent parameters, what's the proper way to resolve a missing parameter?

Tags: ios, objective-c, siri, sirikit

I am coding a SendPaymentIntent handler:

This is the header:

```
#import <Intents/Intents.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CNBIntentHandler : INExtension <INSendPaymentIntentHandling>

@end
```

And this is the implementation:

```
#import "CNBIntentHandler.h"
#import <Contacts/Contacts.h>

@interface CNBIntentHandler()

@end

@implementation CNBIntentHandler

- (id)handlerForIntent:(INIntent *)intent
{
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - INSendPaymentIntentHandling

- (void)resolvePayeeForSendPayment:(INSendPaymentIntent *)intent
                    withCompletion:(void (^)(INPersonResolutionResult * _Nonnull))completion
{
    // Capture intent.payee and search for
    // a match in the Contacts database
}

- (void)resolveCurrencyAmountForSendPayment:(INSendPaymentIntent *)intent
                             withCompletion:(void (^)(INCurrencyAmountResolutionResult * _Nonnull))completion
{
    INCurrencyAmount *currencyAmount = intent.currencyAmount;
    INCurrencyAmountResolutionResult *result = nil;

    if (currencyAmount) {
        // If the currency amount is valid, use it; otherwise,
        // let the user know it is not supported.
    } else {
        // Ask for currency amount
        result = [INCurrencyAmountResolutionResult needsValue];
    }

    completion(result);
}

// Other methods...

@end
```

Now, the problem is:

When the flow of execution enters the `resolveCurrencyAmountForSendPayment:withCompletion:` method *without* a **currencyAmount**, it goes directly to the **else** clause, effectively calling `[INCurrencyAmountResolutionResult needsValue];`. That causes Siri to ask "How much?". The user can then respond with a number. So far, so good. What happens next is what perplexes me:

Rather than calling `resolveCurrencyAmountForSendPayment:withCompletion:` again, SiriKit goes back to calling `resolvePayeeForSendPayment:withCompletion`. That is, the whole parameter resolution process is started from scratch, making my program lose any parameter that had been successfully resolved up to that point.

How should I handle parameter resolution so that my program does not need to start all over again every time a parameter is found to be missing?

Comment: From my experience there is no way like you want. You can save your data in different way maybe.